# Angular $watch event isn't firing on change in window.getSelection().anchorNode

Tags: angularjs, highlight, intervals, watch

I watch for changes in user highlighted text. I trigger base on DOM element being highlighted. I have the following function:

$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return window.getSelection().anchorNode },
          function() { console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode; }

It only fires once when the page loads and never again, regardless of what text I highlight. I highlight text in various spans, text areas on page, and this doesn't fire.

if I add $interval function that does NOTHING, this watch does fire when selection changes after the interval time.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your instance $watch won't work because no $scope variable is being updated and $digest cycle won't start.

You can try use [ngMouseup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseup) directive to get last highlighted text and save it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-mouseup="updateHighlightedText()">lots of text</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.updateHighlightedText = function () {
    $scope.highlightedText = window.getSelection().toString();
}
```

Here is working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xo3n1xwj/1/)

Comment: Good answer. Works well but not for textareas. To support textareas you could add [jQuery.selection](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/) plugin. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/kr78s361/).

Comment: Gentlemen, I very much appreciate your time on this matter. $scope not being updated is what was driving me crazy. And now I know. Much thanks !!!